# How to Fix org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: after update selenium library

Tags: selenium, testng

I updated Pom File

```
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
```

and

```
<artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
```

Now i am trying to run simple test case look like

```
@BeforeMethod
public void before() {
    driver=new ChromeDriver();

}
@Test
public void mytest() {
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());


            }


@AfterMethod
public void aftermethod() {
    driver.close();
}
```

Its give me the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
```

If we downgrade the version then its work.Can anyone help me to fixed?

Comment: No luck. I used the same version and I am using eclipse

Comment: Hit and Trial solution: Delete the repository manually from /users/.m2 folder and after then run again the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you add the chromdriver.exe into the `PATH` environment.

Or you can specify `webdriver.chrome.driver` in code as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", <chromeDriverPath>);
driver=new ChromeDriver();
```